# FAL & Flexform viewhelper

Tags: typo3, view-helpers, fal, flexform

To oputput a FAL image in Flexform, I need a viewhelper. Ok. but, what if I got more fields in the flexform so that I need to get for example TEXTinput fields , Selectfields
AND the FAL image (which is related to sys_file_reference)? Is it possible to build a viewhelper which can handle this? Is there an example for it?
I stuck a bit ^^

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it. See typo3 11.x.x for functionality